# Get results submitted criterion. PHP-MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, filter, phpquery

Hi I'm trying to do filter through the form with which it is set by the user criterion to return the items, which include those criteria.

Code:

```
$filter = " SELECT * FROM images WHERE (id = '$_GET[numPic]' OR id = NULL)  OR (img_content = '$_GET[nmPic]' OR img_content = NULL) OR (category = '$_GET[picCat]' OR category = NULL) OR (price <= '$_GET[priceTo]' OR price = NULL)";
                $resFilter = $connect->query($filter);

                if ($resFilter->num_rows > 0) 
                {

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resFilter))
                    {

                        //show results...

                    }

                }
            }
```

With this application if I submit my two parameters brings all elements with one parameter and all elements with the other parameter, not just the items which include both parameters. Please tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you can **NOT** ever test antyhing for equality with null. **NOTHING** can be equal to null, including itself. that's why there's `is [not] null`.

Comment: OK, I tried without null, but again return the same result. If someone can tell me how it should be Formulation application will'm very grateful to him.

Comment: You have to change all your `id=NULL` with `id IS NULL`... but, if all fields allows `NULL` values, your query will returns **ALL** the rows of the table. If you want match rows with almost one of the criterion you have to delete all `NULL` criteria: something like `SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$_GET[numPic]' OR img_content='$_GET[nmPic]' (etc...)`